Is the closed convex hull of a metrizable space metrizable too?
Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, and $w$ its weak topology. Assume that $C$ is a $w$-compact and $w$-metrizable subset of $X$. It is true that the closed convex hull of $C$, denoted by $\overline{\mathrm{Conv}}(C)$, is also $w$-metrizable? We can assume is reflexive.
My attempt is the following. I know the following results, see, for instance, Aliprantis and Border, Infinite Dimensional Analysis. A Hitchhiker’s Guide, Springer:
Theorem 1: The continuous image of a compact metric space in a Hausdorff space is metrizable.
Theorem 2: The countable product of metrizable spaces is metrizable.
Now, let $\Lambda:=\{(\lambda_{n})_{n\geq 1}\subset [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}: \sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n}=1\}$ which, by Theorem 2 is metrizable and it is compact (Tychonoff theorem). Likewise,   $C^{\mathbb{N}}$ is also compact and metrizable.
Let us define the function $f:\Lambda \times C ^{\mathbb{N}} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathrm{Conv}}(C)$ as
$$
f(\lambda,x):=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n} x_{n},
$$
for each $\lambda:=(\lambda_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in \Lambda$ and $x:=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in C^{\mathbb{N}}$. As $f(\Lambda \times C ^{\mathbb{N}})=\overline{\mathrm{Conv}}(C)$, by Theorem 1, if $f$ is weak-to-weak continuous then $\overline{\mathrm{Conv}}(C)$  will be metrizable.
Many thanks for your comments in advance.

Does $w$-metrizable means that the weak topology is metrizable? In this case, already the unit ball (and, consequently, any subset) is $w$-metrizable.

An infinite dimensional Banach sapce $X$ weak topology is never metrizable (in fact,  bouded subsets of a Banach spaces endowed the weak topology are metrizables if and onfli if the dual of X is separable). Here, $w$-metrizable means that $B$ is metrizable if we consider $B$ endowed with the weak topology

I'm leaning towards a no here. I'd be using the Nagata–Smirnov metrization theorem focusing on the countably locally finite (that is, -locally finite) basis. As you noted any continuous curve is metrizable, but as you may know, these curves can be quite wild (e.g. think of Brownian motion) On the other hand the weak topology of $X$ does not to be that refined. Just an idea to try.

Are you sure that the set $\Lambda$ is compact? I mean, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact by Tychonoff hteorem but I don't think that $\Lambda$ is closed in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ (take $e_1 = (1,0,0,\dots)$, $e_2 = (0,1,0,\dots)$ etc. then $e_n \in \Lambda$ for every $n$ but this sequence converges to the sequence of zeroes which is not an element of $\Lambda$).

Note first that for each $\lambda=(\lambda_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in \Lambda$ and each $x=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in C^{\mathbb{N}}$ the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda_nx_n$ weakly converges unconditionally (that is, any permutation of the summands does not change the sum), so the map $f$ is defined correctly.
For each $\varphi\in X^*$ we have
$$\varphi(f(\lambda,x))=\varphi\left(\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda_nx_n\right)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)$$
and the series converges absolutely.
We claim that the map $f$ is continuous, when $X$ is endowed with the weak topology $w$ and $C^{\mathbb N}$ is the Tychonoff product of the spaces $C$ endowed with the subspace topology of $(X,w)$.
To show this it suffices to show that for each $\lambda=(\lambda_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in \Lambda$, $x=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in C^{\mathbb{N}}$, each $\varphi\in X^*$, and each open neighborhood $U$ of $\varphi(f(\lambda,x))$ there exist a natural number $m$ and for each natural $n\le m$ an open subset $V_n\ni \lambda_n$ of $[0,1]$ and a weakly open subset $W_n\ni x_n$ of $X$ such that
$\varphi(f(V\times W))\subset U$, where
$$V=\left(\prod_{n=1}^m V_n\times \prod_{n=m+1}^\infty [0,1]\right)\cap\Lambda\mbox{ and }
W=\left(\prod_{n=1}^m W_n\times \prod_{n=m+1}^\infty X\right)\cap C^{\mathbb N}.$$
Since the set $C$ is weakly compact, three exists $K\ge 1$ such that $|\varphi(y)|\le K$ for each $y\in C$.
Pick $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\{t\in\mathbb R:|t-\varphi(f(\lambda,x))|<\varepsilon\}\subset U$.
Pick $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \lambda_n<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{5K}$.
Then
$$\left|\varphi(f(\lambda,x))-\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)\right|=
\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)\right|\le \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\lambda_n\left|\varphi(x_n)\right|\le \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\lambda_n K<\frac{\varepsilon}5.$$
For each natural $n\le m$ put
$$V_n=\left\{\mu\in [0,1]:|\mu-\lambda_n|<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{5mK}\right\}\mbox{ and }
W_n=\left\{y\in X:|\varphi(y)-\varphi(x_n)|<\tfrac{\varepsilon}5\right\}.$$
Let $\lambda'=(\lambda'_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in V$ and $x'=(x'_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in W$ be any points.
Note first that
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \lambda'_n=1-\sum_{n=1}^m \lambda'_n=
\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda_n-\sum_{n=1}^m \lambda'_n=
\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\lambda_n+\sum_{n=1}^m \lambda_n-\lambda'_n\le $$
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\lambda_n+\sum_{n=1}^m |\lambda_n-\lambda'_n|<
\frac{\varepsilon}{5K}+\sum_{n=1}^m \tfrac{\varepsilon}{5mK}\le \frac{2\varepsilon}{5K}.$$
Similarly to the above we can show that
$\left|\varphi(f(\lambda',x'))-\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)\right|<\tfrac{2\varepsilon}5$.
We have
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)-\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)\right|=$$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)-\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)\right|=$$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)-\lambda'_n\varphi(x_n)+\lambda'_n\varphi(x_n)-\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)\right|=$$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n(\varphi(x'_n-x_n))+(\lambda'_n-\lambda_n)\varphi(x_n)\right|\le $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\lambda'_n(\varphi(x'_n-x_n))\right|+\left|(\lambda'_n-\lambda_n)\varphi(x_n)\right|\le $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\left|(\varphi(x'_n-x_n))\right|+\left|\lambda'_n-\lambda_n\right|K< $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\lambda'_n\frac{\varepsilon}5+\frac{\varepsilon}{5mK}K\right)\le \frac{\varepsilon}5+\frac{\varepsilon}5=\frac{2\varepsilon}{5}.$$
Finally, we have
$$\left|\varphi(f(\lambda,x))-\varphi(f(\lambda',x'))\right|\le$$
$$\left|\varphi(f(\lambda,x))-\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)\right|+
\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda_n\varphi(x_n)-\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)\right|+
\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda'_n\varphi(x'_n)-\varphi(f(\lambda',x'))\right|<
\frac{\varepsilon}5+\frac{2\varepsilon}5+\frac{2\varepsilon}5=\varepsilon.$$

Thanks @Alex for your response. I will see it in detail. What do you think of the my bellow response?

I hace focused the problem form a different perspective. What do you think about the above reasoning?
As $C$ is $w$-compact and $w$-metrizable, by the Urysohn metrization theorem, $C$ is second countable and, in particular, $w$-separable. So, $C$ is separable. It is follows then that $\overline{Conv}(C)$ is also separable.
Let $(\xi_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a dense sequence in $\overline{Conv}(C)-\overline{Conv}(C)$. For each $n\geq 1$, by the Hahn-Canach theorem, there is a sequence $(\xi_{n}^{*})_{n\geq 1}\subset X^{*}$ such that, for each $n\geq 1$, $\|\xi_{n}^{*}\|=1$ and $\xi_{n}^{*}(\xi_{n})=\|\xi_{n}\|$. For any $z\in \overline{Conv}(C)-\overline{Conv}(C)$, with $z\neq \theta$, the null vector of $X$, let $r>0$ and $n\geq 1$ such that $\|\xi_{n}-z\|>r$. As
$$
|\xi_{n}^{*}(z)-\xi_{n}^{*}(\xi_{n})| \leq \|\xi_{n}^{*}\| \|z-\xi_{n}\|<r,
$$
it follows that $\xi_{n}^{*}(z)>\xi_{n}^{*}(\xi_{n})-r=\|\xi_{n}\|-r$. Taking $0<r<\frac{1}{4}\|z\| $, we have $\|\xi_{n}\|>\frac{3}{4}\|z\|$ and hence
$$
\xi_{n}^{*}(z)>\xi_{n}^{*}(\xi_{n})-r=\|\xi_{n}\|-r>\frac{1}{2}\|z\|>0.
$$
In other words, for $x,y\in \overline{Conv}(C)$ with $x\neq y$ there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $\xi_{n}^{*}(x-y)\neq 0$
Then, the mapping
$$
d(x,y):=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{| \xi_{n}^{*}(x-y)   |}{2^{n}},\quad \textrm{for each } x,y\in \overline{Conv}(C),
$$
is well defined (as $\overline{Conv}(C)$ is bounded) and, noticing the above considerations, a distance in $\overline{Conv}(C)$.
Finally, as $\overline{Conv}(C)$, by the well known Krein–Smulian theorem, is $w$-compact, the identity function from $(\overline{Conv}(C),w)$ into $\overline{Conv}(C),d)$ is continuous, and hence, an homeomorphism. So, $\overline{Conv}(C) $ is $w$-metrizable.
